# Partial Sums of equal series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If two infinite series are equal, are there partial sums equal? If not, is there any relationship at all between their partial sums?

Comment: Partial sums need not be equal, but the sequence of partial sums would converge to the same number (by a definition of convergence)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick counterexample:

$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...=2$

$\frac{4}{3}+\frac{4}{9}+\frac{4}{27}+...=2$

$\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{32}+...=2$

Basically: No, and no.

Answer (score 0):

If you denote the partial sums of two series as $S_1, S_2, S_3, \ldots$ and $T_1, T_2, T_3, \ldots$, and both converge to the same limit $L$, then you can find an $n_1$ for which $n > n_1$ implies $|S_n - L| < \epsilon$ and $n > n_2$ implies $|T_n - L| < \epsilon$. Picking $N = \max\{n_1, n_2\}$ ensures both series' $n$th partial sums are within $\epsilon$ of the desired limit for all $n > N$.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way to visualize this is to take a serie $\sum a_n$ and build another sequence $(b_n)_n$ from the terms of $(a_n)_n$ but while inserting infinitely many zeros.

By construction it is obvious that they have the same sum, but for any given function $f$ you can choose to insert more zeros in order that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i\neq\sum\limits_{i=0}^{f(n)}b_i$.

Of course when the series are convergent we have $L-A_N=\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{\infty}a_i\to 0$ and $L-B_N=\sum\limits_{i=N+1}^{\infty}b_i\to 0$ when $N\to\infty$ so in case the series converge to $L\neq 0$ (it is in particular the case for series with positive terms) then their partial sums are equivalent $\Rightarrow A_N=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}a_i\sim B_N=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}b_i\sim L$.

But this is not necessary true for sequences with positive and negative terms which sums to zero or simply for the remainders $(A_N-L)$ and $(B_N-L)$ in that matter.

For instance let's look at $\{a_0=-1,a_n=1/2^n\}$ and $\{b_0=-1,b_{n^2}=a_n$ and $b_n=0$ otherwise$\}$.

$A_N=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}a_i=-1+\frac 12\frac{1-1/2^N}{1-1/2}=-\frac{1}{2^N}\quad$  and $B_{N^2}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N^2}b_i=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N}a_i=A_N$.

So $B_N$ and $A_N$ are **not equivalent** : $B_N\sim~\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt N}}$ while $A_N\sim\frac{1}{2^N}$.

So if we can do that with the same sequence by just inserting zeros, you can imagine that with two random series that just happen to have the same sum, not much can be said in general about comparing their partial sums.